# Use toks or commands in selectlanguage from babel

Tags: macros, babel, languages

I'm currently working on creating a generic invoice in LaTeX.
Later I don't want to change the document, but a little section which only contains variables. It works fine for now, but now I want to introduce a variable which switches the language between english and ngerman.
Because \selectlanguage of the babel package just works in the document section, I have to define a variable for that.

I tried it with

```
\def\documentLanguage{english}
```

and

```
\newcommand{\documentLanguage}{english}
```

And then in the document section with

```
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{\documentLanguage}
```

Neither of these worked, 
because of the error "You haven't defined documentLanguage yet". I think the \ somehow gets removed and the parser just reads "documentLanguage" as string.

Is there a way to fix this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: `\expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{\documentLanguage}` should work, but probably there are better methods, if you're implementing a class.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, it works!
Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
\expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{\documentLanguage}
```

(for historical reasons, `\selectlanguage` stringifies its argument, so a control sequence there is not expanded).

I'd prefer a different approach, but this requires knowing the details of your implementation.